# Has "To Autumn" ever ended the first stanza with something other than a period?

Tags: poetry, textual-history, john-keats, orthography

Is there an edition of Keats' poem *To Autumn* which ends the first stanza with something other than a period (full stop)? Do we have an edition of it that Keats saw through the press?

I think the stanza ought to end with a colon but I have not seen it printed that way. It ought to end with a colon because as it stands it is merely a sentence fragment, and I have never known Keats to write sentence fragments (ejaculations are a kind of sentence); with a colon, the stanza is an extended equivalent to "O Autumn" leading up to the next stanza, which begins with a complete sentence.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]. Thank you for posting this as a question!

Answer (score 2):

‘To Autumn’ was first published in [*Lamia, Isabella, the Eve of St Agnes and Other Poems*](https://archive.org/details/dli.granth.35936) (London: Taylor and Hessey, 1820) where it starts on [page 137](https://archive.org/details/dli.granth.35936/page/136/mode/2up) and you can see for yourself that the first stanza of the poem ends with a full stop. The book was published in July 1820, a couple of months before Keats departed for Italy, so it seems likely that he had the opportunity to correct the proofs.

I think there is little real difficulty here: those readers who successfully thread the maze of syntax and realize that Keats has only given them a noun phrase can easily fix things, for example, by imagining an elided “thou art” somewhere along the way.

A [search of the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22clammy%20cells%20who%20hath%22&sin=TXT&sort=date) finds hundreds of editions of the poem, but nearly all of them have the full stop after “cells”. Nonetheless, I did find one edition with a colon:

> [image: The top of page 418 showing the first stanza of ‘To Autumn’ ending with a colon.]
>
> <sub>Anon, ed. (1882). [*Fifth Book of Reading Lessons*, p. 418](https://archive.org/details/c2fifthbookofrea00toro/page/418/mode/2up). Toronto: Thomas Nelson.</sub>